# Moving a part of an image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview, touchimageview

I have two images in a relative layout, image 2 is placed on image 1, now I want to move just a specific part of image 2 without moving any other part of image 2.  How can I do this?

Below is my xml code, I have added image2 dynamically in this same layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    tools:context="sampleapp.com.cam2.Main2Activity"
                    android:id="@+id/rl2">

      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView222"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your xml code?

Comment: @gj_ ihave edited the post. please check it